# Choosing values so that a matrix is not-diagonalizable

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets say we have the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 5\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}$

And we want to determine for which values of $a$, the matrix is not diagonalizable. How do you approach such a problem?

Comment: For an "upper triangular matrix," the diagonal values are the eigenvalues. If the eigenvalues are distinct, then the matrix is diagonalizable. So the only case you need to check is $a=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

- What are the eigenvalues of your matrix?
- What can you say about eigenvectors of different eigenvalues?
- A $2\times 2$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do you know the Jordan form?

Hint: A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has an eigenbasis.  Can you find the eigenvectors of this matrix for various values of $a$?

Comment: I don't think invoking the Jordan form is needed here...

Comment: @5xum Invoking the Jordan form is not needed, but the set of ideas behind the problem are very closely related to understanding what the structure of the Jordan form is telling you.

Comment: OK, good point. Anyway, it's good to have diverse answers.